WSL: Forward my windows ssh-agent works, but opening a ssh connection does not?
I mostly followed this guide https://stuartleeks.com/posts/wsl-ssh-key-forward-to-windows/#final-solution and used this handy script to automate the task https://github.com/rupor-github/wsl-ssh-agent/blob/master/docs/wsl-ssh-agent-relay .
I was able to:

Enable the SSH-Agent service in windows amd add my github key with ssh-add
Add my GitHub key to it and confirm it works with ssh -T -A git@github.com and returns Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Open a socket between Windows and WSL with npiperelay.exe and socat
Use SSH_AUTH_SOCK to link the linux ssh-agent to the windows socket
I can see the keys I added in Windows now with ssh-add -l whenever the socket is open

BUT when I tried to open an actual SSH connection with ssh -T -A -vvvv git@github.com I see the following debug line:
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed

I'm a bit at a loss here. Why can I get the agent identities with the cli but ssh can't?
I've added the following already to my linux and windows ~/.ssh/config:
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes

I'm not sure where or if I need it but I read is somewhere.
Some additional information about my system:

Windows 11 23H2
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
WSL-Version: 2.3.24.0
Kernelversion: 5.15.153.1-2

Does anyone have ANY ideas what else I can try?
Or what the issue is?

Just a note, the phrase "I mostly followed..." tells us we're missing information. While I think you've listed the specific steps below that in the ordered list, if you were to edit your post to remove the ambiguity it would make your question much better. Start with a clear description of the problem (not in the title), tell us precisely what you've done, and then summarize and restate, or clearly state, the question you're asking. Leave the links only for attribution, but do not make us feel we need to visit those links to understand what you've done so far.
